# Prove that if $p_1, p_2$ are two norms on $\mathbb{R}^N$ , then $p(x) := max (p_1(x), p_2(x))$ is a norm.

Tags: analysis, normed-spaces

I'm asking this on here because it seems a bit deceptively simple. To show that $p(x)$ is a norm, we just need to verify the three conditions that define a norm. Then, we quickly show that since each of the other norms are indeed norms, those properties translate through the "join" that defines $p(x)$.

Comment: You write "I am asking this", but in fact you are not asking anything. What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The triangle inequality is the only condition to check. The remaining two conditions are obvious. So, $p_i(x+y)\le p_i(x)+p_i(y)\le p(x)+p(y)$ $(i=1,2)$, whence the desired inequality trivially follows.

Notice that this argument holds for any normed space, not olny $\Bbb R^N$.